# Service Layer in Vue.JS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

In Angular, there's a specific "service" layer intended to hold mockup services returning dummy data initially, which are replaced with real calls to the backing RESTful services as development on a project proceeds.

In Vue, is there a recommended location or layer in which to put such remote calls using axios? I can see them being placed inside the methods of a Vuex singleton or scattered through the `script` portions of single-file components... I imagine also that there might be some way to provide them to components via dependency injection.

What is the best practice?

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're using Vuex, you can place Service components that wrap your Axios calls, which are then called from the vuex store.

So the hierarchy goes `Component` -> `Store` -> `Service Component` -> `Axios`